# FossilSCM, ignoring files on add

Tags: fossil

I've done some research, but honestly can't seem to figure this out.

You can set some set some options to have *fossil extras* ignore files, but not *fossil add*?  The configuration options through the web interface is great, and I'm pleased that it does work for the extras command, but it doesn't apply to the add command?

How does one configure fossil to ignore files on **fossil add .**?

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`settings ignore-glob` command](http://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/help?cmd=settings) to list the directories/files to ignore as a comma-separated list.

1. On your repository's [web interface](http://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/help?cmd=ui), go to the *Admin* menu, select *Settings* and type the comma-separated list of directories to ignore; for example: `*/*.suo,*/*/bin/*,*/*/obj/*`.
2. Alternatively, on the command line you can type `fossil settings ignore-glob` to list the applied ignore list, or `fossil settings ignore-glob` *list-of-files*.
3. You can also create/edit the `.fossil-settings/ignore-glob` at the root of the project and insert the comma-separated list of files/directories to ignore; I have not personally tested this, but I remember reading this online.

For example, on the command line you can do:

```
fossil settings ignore-glob "*/*.suo,*/*/bin/*,*/*/obj/*"
```

This would ignore all `.suo` files in every subdirectory at the Fossil repository root tree, and all the files in the `bin` and `dir` subdirectories at the each of the directory in the root directory.

Answer (score 7):

If you want something like .gitignore or .hgignore, you can read https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/settings.wiki

```
mkdir .fossil-settings
echo '*/*.suo' >> .fossil-settings/ignore-glob
echo '*/*/bin/*' >> .fossil-settings/ignore-glob
fossil add .fossil-settings
```

Comment: ```s,(ignore-glob),.fossil-settings/\1,``` ?

Answer (score 5):

See [this check-in](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/ci/be3d2154da66a4cc3d1937f44f3a551efd26ca0c) in fossil development repository. What you asked for has been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

very recent versions of Fossil have an `addremove` command that will add all extras and remove all missing files in your working tree. The `--ignore-glob` switch is available.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Otherwise you could probably just do :

```
fossil extras | xargs fossil add
```

Comment: I think the OP was actually trying to get the effect of your other answer. Its a feature I've wished for myself as well.

Comment: Of course, but at that time it was not implemented. Now it is. I have sometimes the feeling that drh reads posts about fossil or sqlite on stackoverflow as well as tickets on his repository.

Comment: He has commented on stackoverflow before, so I wouldn't be surprised if he's still following it. Considering how principled he is about SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html), it seems likely he's interested in continuously improving fossil as long as it fits his vision (he refused a pull request for hooks because the solution wasn't 100% cross-platform, for example).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 (not tested on other platforms)

If you do

`fossil add *.*`

All ignore-glob settings are ignored (all files are added).

If you do

`fossil add .`

then ignore-glob settings are used.

Answer (score 0):

It is because I have already added the file, and fossil skipped the duplicated "add" operation, OMG.